# Changing name of Xcode App uncertainty

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval, bundle-identifier, xcode-project

Today I changed the name of my iOS app. However, in Xcode the bundle identifier with com.yourname.appname is still that the old name. Didn't change bundle identifier, didn't change anything in xcode besides the name of app on UIImageView. Can I send to Apple for review on the xcode project everything named the way it was even though in iTunes connect I changed the name to new name of app too or would this be an issue with Apple's app review and cause my app to get rejected?

Comment: "Didn't change bundle identifier, didn't change anything in xcode besides the name of app on UIImageView" Then you didn't change the name of the app. All you changed was an image.

Comment: I changed the name of the app in storyboard's UIImageViews. So now when I launch the app on device it has new name. I also changed the name of the app under TITLE in iTunes connect. Would Apple review have an issue with this if I leave bundle identifier to old name? The difference is 1 letter really.

Comment: You _should_ leave the bundle identifier the same. The problem is that you have not actually changed the name of the app.

Comment: Would Apple review board have an issue with this? Could my app get rejected for this?

Comment: My point is that you have not actually _done_ anything. There is nothing to have an issue with. But it's going to be weird because your image views are going to show one name and the name on the device is going to be a different name, because you have not actually changed the name of the app.

Comment: I want everything to match obviously. I use Xcode 6.1 and I read that name changing for Xcode 6 is different than Xcode 5. What do I have to do to change old name to new name in Xcode?

Comment: You need to change the bundle name (or even better, the bundle display name). That is what the user will see under the icon on the springboard.

Comment: But I don't have to make any changes in apple developer member center's certificates/identifiers/profiles like a change in bundle identifier?

Comment: It would be foolish to change the bundle identifier. That would not rename the app - it would make this _a different app entirely_. Is that what you want? I don't think so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't care about the bundle id.

It only needs to be a bundle identifier and what Apple recommends is that you use an identifying bundle built as a reverse domain, e.g. *com.mycompany.appname*.

The bundle id name is a recommendation, but it's not mandatory.

Not changing the bundle id won't be a problem with Apple's review process.